# How I can add more than 12 tabs to my facebook fan page

Tags: facebook, api

I am having a facebook fan page with more than 12 tabs added but only admin can see all of them, the normal user only see 12 tabs. How can I make my users see all of tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make them see more than that limit. You need to prioritize. As this limit is trying to point out, users aren't going to scroll through many apps to find something. Focus on making some apps really well suited to your page.